# Is it possible to auto-update a chrome extension published on the chrome web store?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

The docs are very unclear about this. I get that you can autoupdate your extension by bumping the version number if you self host your extension. However what I don't know is if you can self host while still publishing to the chrome web store.

I can't believe that Google would make you manually update your extensions via a web interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is now a way to update extensions hosted in CWS programmatically (since [March 2014](http://blog.chromium.org/2014/03/new-monetization-and-publishing-options_11.html)) by using [Webstore API](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/using_webstore_api#uploadexisitng).

After registering for the API and authorizing through OAuth 2.0, you can [push an update](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/webstore_api/items/update) for an existing item:

```sh
curl \
-H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN"  \
-H "x-goog-api-version: 2" \
-X PUT \
-T $FILE_NAME \
-v \
https://www.googleapis.com/upload/chromewebstore/v1.1/items/$APP_ID
```

Documentation is not clear whether this creates a draft or not; in any case, [publishing is also possible](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/webstore_api/items/publish) through the API.

Please note that it will still be subject to automatic review checks, so the actual update will only be available after they complete (usually under an hour).

Comment: It would be nice if someone could experiment and confirm whether the update method publishes the update automatically, or is it considered a draft.

Comment: How to obtain a token, when using the Service API?

Comment: @Rias See [this guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2). You will need to create a project in the Developers Console and enable the API for it to get API keys.

Comment: @Xan - It is possible to publish the update automatically using the API. I use the API to auto-publish the extension which I push to the master branch of my extension repo. See the utils/ directory in https://github.com/robertknight/passcards for scripts.

Answer (score 9):

When you publish to Chrome Web Store (CWS), CWS hosts your extension and you loose control over [update_url](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/autoupdate.html) attribute in `manifest.json` (it's overriten by CWS specific link). When you decide to make new version of your CWS-hosted extension available, you simply upload it (with higher version number) to CWS (via [developer dashboard](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/dashboard)). After that, you just wait for Chrome auto-update feature to do all the work.

Each Chrome performs, in the background and without users direct permission, a routine checks in CWS (or somewhere else if extension is self-hosted) making sure that all extensions are up to date. If new version of any extension (or app) is available, Chrome performs an auto-update (if [extension's permissions haven't increased](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permission_warnings.html)).

Comment: ok that's what I feared. This is completely ridiculous, I am used to deploying new code throughout the day with just a `git push` and now I'm gonna have to do all this manually. Maybe I can try a phantomJS script

Comment: Continuous deployment for Chrome extensions? Sounds cool! I also like the [phantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) idea. Good luck!

Comment: well unfortunately the uploading script is so complicated (not to mentioned hard to reverse engineer because of the minification) that I can't get it to work with phantomJS.

Comment: instead of trying to reverse engineer the minified script, you could use something like BurpSuite and trace the HTTP messages. You can then replicate those easily with PhantomJS.