# chrome extension auto-update strategy

Tags: google-chrome-extension, auto-update, chrome-web-store

I want to update my chrome extensions automatically or via command line. These could be archived using [Autoupdating](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/autoupdate), but only for hosted extension. Autoupdating is [not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13139627/is-it-possible-to-auto-update-a-chrome-extension-published-on-the-chrome-web-sto) for extension hosted in Chrome Web Store. Manual updating through web portal is very tiring.

It is possible to use directly linking js file to external web site, but it will not work for offline use case. We could add appcache to background page, but will that work?

An desperate approach is store js files in indexedDB and inject it.

Is there any better solution?

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say it's "not supported" by CWS-hosted extensions?

Comment: @Xan updated for clarity.

Comment: I assume you're not aware of [Webstore API](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/using_webstore_api#uploadexisitng).

Comment: I've updated the question you linked with a new answer. I think this question deserves a separate answer (regarding your "hosting script externally" approach)

Comment: @Xan Yes, it answered my question. :-) I will try out. Any command line util?

Comment: [`curl`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) is a command-line util ;)

Comment: haha, Oauth 2 dance is not easy. Many be curl has oauth2 support.